# How to store frequency dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3

My users have the fallowing frequency options: Daily, Weekly, Biweekly, Monthly.
Also for the last tree they have the option to choose which days, for example on weekly/biweekly they can choose every (Monday, Tuesday, Friday) and for monthly (10, 15, 25, 30).

For the weekly frequency I can get the days of the week which they selected, in rails they are from 0-6(Sunday-Saturday).

So I came with the table:
Settings: setting_id, resource_id, frequency(daily, weekly, biweekly, monthly), days[]: [0, 1, 2]

Now I need to build a postgresql DB view daily which needs the `resource_id` from my `Settings` table and should get only the resources where the frequency and days were scheduled for current day(now()).

One solution that I can think of, is to use the postgresql `CASE` function and check to see what type of frequency was set for the `resource`,in the case block I can parse the current date to get the day number or the week number with the day number of the week and compare them with what was stored in the table.

Is there a better way of doing this, because I can see some performance issues with the DB view.

Another option will be I guess to have different views for each report.

Comment: How abaout storing frequency in `interval`? Values will be `'1 day'`, `'1 week'`, `'2 weeks'` & `'1 month'` in your special cases. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. One possibility is to use a string, and encode the frequency into a [cron-like syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

That is a well know format. It's not immediate to read, but it is excellent to store somewhere, for instance in a file (like `cron` does) or in a database field.

There are Ruby libraries, such as [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and [`rufus-scheduler`](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) that already deals with the hassle of converting a cron syntax into a Ruby representation, and vice-versa.

Therefore you can write

```
every :day, :at => '12:20am'
```

or

```
every '3h'
at '2030/12/12 23:30:00'
```

and get a nicely formatted cron schedule definition. You can pull the parser of one of those libraries into your project, and use it to convert your database serialized string into a Ruby representation, and vice-versa.